# using dojo text box with spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, dojo

I am a backend developer trying to use a dojo text box in a Spring MVC3 Application.

The page has a text box and a dojo data grid below it. Text box is used to capture search criteria. When user enters value on the text box and clicks ENTER, it should trigger a Spring Controller which would search based on the criteria provided in text box in a data grid.

Questions are

*1. How do I do this in dojo and not plain javascript. I would not want the entire page to be resubmitted.

*2. How can the controller retrieve the values entered in the text box. Will they have to be passed as @ModelAttributes or appear as @RequestParam

Answer (score 0):

> Text box is used to capture search criteria. When user enters value on
>   the text box and clicks ENTER, it should trigger a Spring Controller
>   which would search based on the criteria provided in text box

On submit, you need to fire dojo xhr.get() AJAX call with URL which maps the Spring controller.

```
var getAll = function (URL){
    var xhrArgs = {
            url : URL, // e.g. localhost:8080/projectname/entity?param1=value1
            handleAs : "json",
            headers : {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            }
        };
    return dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
};
```

And in the spring controller, you need to map this url to a mehthod. If it's a single value coming to controller @RequestParam would be better to use

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/entity")
        public List<Model> someMethod(@RequestParam("param1")String keyword) {
}
```

Comment: Ravi, Thanks for your response. I read more about dojo xhr and trying to understand why the handleAs property has to be defined as "json".

Comment: It's could be anything. I presented my example. It's suggest how you handle the response from the server. It's depend on in which format your server gives data

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I was getting a syntax error if the response was handled as json. Even as a text, xhrGEt was not working though the url was correct (and works when pasted in a browser) I have raised this as a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606200/spring-mvc3-with-dojogrid-and-xhrget)